# Setting aws s3 file permission to public after upload in Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am developing a web application. In my application, I am implementing file uploaded feature. I store the uploaded file in the aws s3 bucket. I am uploading the file to the s3 bucket as follow.

```
 $photo_file_path = $request->file('image_file')->store(
            'images/artworks/gallery-images/'.uniqid(),  's3'
          );
```

The above code is working fine. The file is uploaded to  s3. But the problem is I want the file to be public when it is uploaded to s3 so that the photo can be accessible from url as well.  I set both bucket policy and access control to public.

This is my bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1234566788",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt151234344545",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see my bucket is now public for both access control and bucket policy.
[image]

But when I upload the file from Laravel, it is uploaded to the bucket, but the file is still hidden from the public. So, how can I change the file permission to public once the file is uploaded, please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Laravel provides different methods to store the files.

One of the easiest way is to use [`storePublicly()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#file-visibility):

```
$photo_file_path = $request->file('image_file')->storePublicly(
        'images/artworks/gallery-images/'.uniqid()
      );
```

Answer (score 14):

if all your stored files can or should have public you can add `'visibility' => 'public'`, so any file stored in the drive will have public visibility :

```
 's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
            'region' => ('AWS_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

if not, you can configure another drive with same settings including the public flag:

```
 's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
            'region' => ('AWS_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),

        ],
 's3Public' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
            'region' => ('AWS_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

and then just call store selecting the drive with public visibility:

```
$photo_file_path = $request->file('image_file')->store(
            'images/artworks/gallery-images/'.uniqid(),  's3Public'
          );
```

Comment: 'visibility' => 'public', is very important .esle u can not see any file .

Answer (score 0):

Setting `filesystems.disks.s3.visibility` to `public` works perfectly.